# Encapsulate Boost ublas matrix operator ()

Tags: c++

Considering the following class:

```
namespace ublas = boost::numeric::ublas;
class Foo {
private:
    ublas::compressed_matrix<float> foo_mtr_;
}
```

I want to encapsulate `operator()` in such a way that

```
Foo foo;
foo(2, 3) = 3.0f;
```

would be equivalent to

```
foo_mtr_(2, 3) = 3.0f;
```

I've tried

```
float &operator () (int i, int_type j) {
    return foo_mtr_(i, j);
}
```

But it does not compile:

> error: binding reference of type ‘float&’ to ‘const float’ discards
>   qualifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ublas::compressed_matrix<T>` has defined types `reference` and `const_reference`, you should use them instead `T&` or `const T&`. Rewrite your `operator()(int,int)` as follows

```
ublas::compressed_matrix<float>::reference operator () (int i, int_type j) {
    return foo_mtr_(i, j);
}
```

Comment: Hi, rafix07. I've tried this before, but it does not compile: 
>invalid initialization of reference of type ‘boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<float>::reference& {aka     boost::numeric::ublas::sparse_matrix_element<boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_matrix<float> >&}’ from expression of type ‘const float’

Comment: It is strange, error means `foo_mtr_(i,i)` returns const float, so `operator()() const` version of `compressed_matrix` was invoked, did you paste actual definition of your `Foo::operator ()()` version ?

Comment: It was a typo, I forgot to remove "&" operator. Thanks for helping me, @rafix07